# admin crontab won't run sudo command

Tags: cron, root, cron-task

```
sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Hi I am getting the above error when ever I try to get the following crontab to run.

```
*/5 * * * * sudo bash /home/admin/scripts/monitor.sh /dev/null 2>&1
```

I am using nano as the editor to edit the admin user crontab - note this is not root user.

EDITOR=nano crontab -e -u admin

Comment: Why do you need sudo for this script? You have to provide password every time or change /etc/sudoers

Comment: @AndreySabitov do I change this line #Defaults    requiretty

Comment: monitor.sh script started with #! /bin/bash?

Comment: I got it to work, by moving it to the root user to run

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) Disable requiretty in sudoers file

2) Permit script execution without password:

```
admin    ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /home/admin/scripts/monitor.sh
```

3) I'm not sure but you don't need specify bash after sudo. Just add #! /bin/bash at the begin of the script

```
*/5 * * * * sudo /home/admin/scripts/monitor.sh /dev/null 2>&1
```

Comment: Three answers in one - (2) please!